# How to query records by current date?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The following code allows me to count the total number of visits that are registered by `IP`:

```
$stmtIP = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visitor_ip WHERE ip_remote=?");
$stmtIP->bind_param("s",$IP_ADDRESS);
$stmtIP->execute();
$count_ip_record = null;
$stmtIP->bind_result($count_ip_record);
$stmtIP->fetch();
$stmtIP->close();

echo $count_ip_record;
```

I have a column in the data table called: `visitor_date` of type `datetime`, records a:

```
2021-01-18 19:40:15
```

Which I want to count the `IP` records by current date. How can I pass that condition to `WHERE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CURDATE` function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visitor_ip WHERE DATE(visitor_date) = CURDATE() AND ip_remote=?
```

Or any date via parameter:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visitor_ip WHERE DATE(visitor_date) = ? AND ip_remote=?";
$stmtIP = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmtIP->bind_param("ss", $date, $IP_ADDRESS);
$stmtIP->execute();
```

If `visitor_date` has index:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visitor_ip "
     . "WHERE (visitor_date BETWEEN ? AND ? + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND ip_remote=?";
$stmtIP = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmtIP->bind_param("sss", $date, $date, $IP_ADDRESS);
$stmtIP->execute();
```

Comment: FYI, calling a function on the column's value ruins the index use

Comment: @YourCommonSense, you're right. The question is closed, but the answer has been updated with the condition for the index anyway.